# htaccess redirect in main folder and sub folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

i have problem in htaccess

here's my project [custom cms] scheme

```
./
   admin
   app
        p1
        p2
   core
   views
   .htaccess
```

in this htaccess file :

i want to make app has its own style

so i add this

`RewriteRule   ^(.*)/admin/(.*)  admin/$2&app=$1              [L]`

now when i add this url

`http://www.site.com/p1/admin/index.php`

it mean

`http://www.site.com/admin/index.php?app=p1`

but i want now to add `.htacces` file in admin path  to control query strings

like this

`http://www.site.com/p1/admin/xxx.xxx?a=1&b=2&c=3 ......`

to compile as

`http://www.site.com/admin/xxx.xxx?app=p1&a=1&b=2&c=3 ......`

thank you

**comment**

please check the schema after i edit it

in the first lik
site.com/p1/admin/xxx.xxx?a=1&b=2&c=3

p1 => application in app path
admin => admin manager

xxx.xxx?a=1&b=2&c=3 => file and query string

in the other link [ real one ]
site.com/admin/xxx.xxx?app=p1&a=1&b=2&c=3

admin => admin manager

xxx.xxx?app=p1&a=1&b=2&c=3 => file and query strings but this one
app=p1

is the application in app path

i will add this comment in post

http://img03.arabsh.com/uploads/image/2014/04/09/0c30424b60f10d.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGBTb.png

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what is the relation between: http://www.site.com/p1/admin/xxx.xxx?a=1&b=2&c=3 ...... and http://www.site.com/admin/xxx.xxx?app=p1&a=1&b=2&c=3 ......

Comment: please check the schema after i edit it

in the first lik
site.com/p1/admin/xxx.xxx?a=1&b=2&c=3

p1 => application in app path
admin => admin manager

xxx.xxx?a=1&b=2&c=3 => file and query string

in the other link [ real one ]
site.com/admin/xxx.xxx?app=p1&a=1&b=2&c=3

admin => admin manager

xxx.xxx?app=p1&a=1&b=2&c=3 => file and query strings but this one
app=p1

is the application in app path

i will add this comment in post

Comment: can you understand me now ??? @Philibobby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want a `?` instead of a `&`, and you want to use the `QSA` flag:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/admin/(.*) admin/$2?app=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: @Safy "QSA" flag means "Query String Append", or append any part of an existing query string to the end of the rule's target query string